# mat-menu with dynamic menu-items renders the same data object instead of the passed object

Tags: angular, angular-material

My problem refers to angular material menu (mat-menu).

I created this repo that demonstrates the problem:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-snymga

The menu renders dynamic set of item, for example if my deck is private, the menu will have an Item "Make Public" and vice versa "Make Private" if the deck is public.

Also each card belongs to a different deck and therefore have different title, card id and I want that each click on the menu will raise an event with the action & id of the card that was triggered.

In the example you can see that cards have different titles and visibility as expected.

The problem is that the menu items that are rendered, are always rendering the same menuData instance instead of the instance of menuData model that is passed as input. as if the mat-menu-items acts as a singelton, instead of making instance per menuData provided.

I also saw that ngInit of ui-card-menu component was initialised only once.

You can see in the repo preview - that all menus of the different deck all have "Make Public" menu item instead of changing according to the visibility of the deck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that when you are cloning the menuData, you are performing a shallow clone, instead of a deep clone. So when you change the id on the menu items, you are changing the id on all the menus.

In your ui-card component, if you change this line, which is doing the shallow clone:

```
this.menuDataCloned = {...this.menuData};
```

Change it to this, which is doing a deep clone:

```
this.menuDataCloned = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.menuData));
```